# java.lang.AssertionError: Activity never becomes requested state

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

I got following error when i executed my unit test

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Activity never becomes requested state "[CREATED, STARTED, RESUMED, DESTROYED]" (last lifecycle transition = "PRE_ON_CREATE")
at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.waitForActivityToBecomeAnyOf(ActivityScenario.java:338)
at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.launchInternal(ActivityScenario.java:272)
at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.launch(ActivityScenario.java:238)
at androidx.test.ext.junit.rules.ActivityScenarioRule.lambda$new$3$ActivityScenarioRule(ActivityScenarioRule.java:98)
at androidx.test.ext.junit.rules.ActivityScenarioRule$$Lambda$3.get(Unknown Source:4)
at androidx.test.ext.junit.rules.ActivityScenarioRule.before(ActivityScenarioRule.java:103)
at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:46)
```

My test code

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LargeTest
class TestHomePageFragment {


    private val intent = Intent(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(), AudioPlayerActivity::class.java).apply {
        flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        putExtra(HomePageArouterConstants.KEY_ID,"1")
    }
    @get:Rule
     val activityRule:ActivityScenarioRule<AudioPlayerActivity> = activityScenarioRule(intent)


    @Test
    fun testVote(){
//        Assert.assertEquals(1,1)
        val scenario = activityRule.scenario
        scenario.moveToState(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
        onView(withId(R.id.linear_layout_like)).perform(click())
    }

}
```

Who has ideas for this problem?

Comment: `ActivityScenario.launch(AudioPlayerActivity.class))` >

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: I've seen this as a flaky behavior on certain devices (e.g. Xiaomi POCO). Pixel devices and emulators were more reliable in this regard.